# Route-guard no longer prevents navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I have built an [angular website](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/) with a bootstrap navbar, where I use the `[routerLinkActive]` in order to highlight the links which indicate where the user is right now.

[image: User is now at /basic/tab-control]

The navlinks which don't route to a page, but just simply contain another dropdown, are protected from activation by adding a route guard to the route:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => false;
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [MyGuard] },
  {
    path: 'carousel',
    loadChildren: () => import('./carousel/carousel.module').then((m) => m.CarouselModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class BasicRoutingModule {}
```

For [angular 13](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qkd4qc?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.module.ts,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json&title=Angular%20Starter) and up until 15 this used to work fine, however for [angular 16](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qkd4qc?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.module.ts,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter) the guard is never triggered. Also not with the [new route guard syntax](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fsj3bt?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.module.ts,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter).

Is this a bug? How can I fix this?

Edit: It even works for [angular 13 with a lambda guard](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-te2xye?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.module.ts,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: What happens if You remove circular `redirectTo: ''` from route? Was it ever needed here?

Comment: That gives me `NG04014: Invalid configuration of route 'basic/'. One of the following must be provided: component, loadComponent, redirectTo, children or loadChildren`

Comment: But it seems that `loadChildren: () => []` does work

Comment: Have you tried moving the guard in the app-routing.module?